# Injecting theme name into front end Best approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

At the min I am replacing _content in the source elements of my cshtml razor to inject the theme name my users are selecting in the admin this works.

But It requires me to place a tag helper on every element this happens.

At Present I am doing

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = AppendVersionAttributeName)]
public class AppendVersionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string AppendVersionAttributeName = "cella-append-version";
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

 public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
 {
     output.Attributes.RemoveAll(AppendVersionAttributeName);
     if (!AppendVersion)
        {
           if (output.Attributes.ContainsName("href"))
            {
                var href = output.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", AppendVersionToUrl(href));
            }
        }

        if (!AppendVersion)
        {
            if (output.Attributes.ContainsName("src"))
            {
                var src = output.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString();

                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("src", AppendVersionToUrl(src));
            }
        }

        if (output.Attributes.ContainsName("href"))
        {
            var href = output.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", AppendThemeNameToUrl(href));
        }
        if (output.Attributes.ContainsName("src"))
        {
            var src = output.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString();
            var replace = AppendThemeNameToUrl(src);
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("src", replace);
        }
        if (output.Attributes.ContainsName("xlink:href"))
        {
            var src = output.Attributes["xlink:href"].Value.ToString();
            var replace = AppDomainNameToImage(src);
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("xlink:href", replace);
        }


    private string AppDomainNameToImage(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var theme = Constants.DomainName + @"/" + _config[Constants.ThemFolderNameConfigKey] + @"/" + _config["Theme"];
    
        url = url.Replace("_DomainName", theme);

        return url;
    }
    private string AppendThemeNameToUrl(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var theme = _config[Constants.ThemFolderNameConfigKey] + @"/"+ _config["Theme"];
        url = url.Replace("_content", theme);

        return url;
    }
    private string AppendVersionToUrl(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var version = _config["Global.AssetVersion"];

        return url.Contains("?") ? $"{url}&v={version}" : $"{url}?v={version}";
    }
  }
```

The function above called

```
  private string AppendThemeNameToUrl(string url)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
      {
            return string.Empty;
      }

      var theme = _config[Constants.ThemFolderNameConfigKey] + @"/"+ _config["Theme"];
      url = url.Replace("_content", theme);

    return url;
  }
}
```

Then I call the tag helper like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" cella-append-version="false" href="~/_content/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

My only concern is this is making an impact on how fast the razor engine returns from the tag helper to present to the user is there a neater way to inject the theme name dynamically to the front end

Comment: @ferikeem of course it matters  and no the tag helpers are run on runtime please dont create confusion discussions when u dont understand the tech

Comment: I'm sorry, I did misunderstand something, what part/why do you think is 'slow'? You are doing the same thing in your new function as above, are those slow too? You have to do the replacement somewhere.